# Vue - How to toggle an item's child across a list of DOM items?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following DOM structure:

```
<item>
  <div>
    <a href="">show details</a>
  </div>
  <div class="details">...</div>
</item>
<item></item>
...
```

And I want to toggle the details `div` whenever `a` is clicked

What's the best way to achieve this in Vue.js ?

Comment: There are many, many ways to achieve this. How are the `<item>` components being created within the DOM? Are they within a `v-for` loop?

Comment: They are generated via php. They are in place as such...

Comment: Do you have access to a unique identifier on a per `<item` basis that we can use as a reference? Either the loop in the index, or an ID from the database, for instance.

Comment: Yes, I can generate that or pretty much anything. I'm new to Vue and was actually pondering if it can be achieved without an id or ref, but I'm open to any sort of solution to give myself a start.

Comment: This feels like a misuse of the framework; you'd be getting a lot more out of Vue if you used it instead of PHP to generate the DOM. A Vue `item` component could contain the logic for its own toggle and then you wouldn't need to be worrying about managing refs across a whole list.

Comment: @DanielBeck Agreed and thanks for the point. I'm just starting out with Vue and trying to make the most out of it any way I can for now. Will probably switch once I get the hang of it.

Comment: IME the learning curve is much shorter if you don't try to do it halfsies. JS frameworks like vue/react/angular use such a different model of how to construct and manage the DOM than traditional jquery/php/other older techniques that you'll end up with lots of complications trying to use them together, and will have a harder time getting to an understanding of how the frameworks are intended to be used

Comment: @DanielBeck I'm also a bit concerned that by using Vue-only to render/manipulate a page the results for Google indexing may suffer.

Comment: That is a factor, true; Googlebot has been able to [parse SPA pages for some time now](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better) but I'm not sure that applies to other search engines.  If SEO is a key concern then SPA frameworks may not be the ideal choice (serverside rendering  is also a possiblilty but it's more complicated to set up.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the fact that you have control over the rendering on the PHP side, I'd say utilizing a simple `$index` variable from your loop to hold access to a list of ID's would be simple enough. If you can pass `$index` from the php method to the component, then you can utilize the below:

```
  <Item>
    <div>
      <a @click="$set(details, $index, !details[$index])">show details</a>
    </div>
    <div class="details" v-show="details[$index]">...</div>
  </Item>
```

Then hold reference to `details` in your component's data definition:

```
data () {
  return {
    //...
    details: {}
  }
}
```

Note the usage of `$set` in the above allows us to creative a reactive property in our `details` object. Utilizing this approach means you are not required to define each index property on the `details` object.

[Here's a simple jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0z3q8oru/) which should help give you a more visual idea of the approach.

Comment: Approved, with the mention that for Vue3 the syntax seems to be `details[$index] = !details[$index]` instead of `$set(details, $index, !details[$index])`